# Can I download WhatsApp on Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0 to 4.04) compatible with WhatsApp?

Comment: If you can see/install it from the Play Store on your phone/tablet, it's supported.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it supports Android 2.1 and up.

[Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp)

Answer (score 3):

Did you check [their website](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/21166563)?

> **Which Android devices are supported?**
>
> We support all Android phones provided they meet the following requirements:
>
> - Your Android phone is running Android OS 2.1 or later.
> - Your Android phone is able to receive SMS or calls during the verification process.
>   You will also need an adequate data plan in order to receive messages when outside the range of a Wi-Fi network.
>
> We do not support tablets or Wi-Fi only devices at this time.